# invalid_grant Returned using Service Account and Google Drive API

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

I've spent 2 days messing around with various Drive API tutorials using a Service Account.

The most recent tutorial i used was this one: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

I keep getting this error when trying to upload a file:

```
ProtocolException was unhandled
Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
```

I installed [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and determined that when `POST /o/oauth2/token` was returning:

```
{
    "error:"invalid_grant"
}
```

I have already triple+ checked the scope of my application.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the time on my server was 5 min fast.

When I corrected the time on the server everything worked.

I believe this was causing some kind of authentication issue because the Google Server time didn't accept the timestamp of the request coming from my server or something along those lines...

(Hope this saves someone some head banging)

Comment: My server was only off about a minute and it was throwing these errors.  I installed an NTP service and everything is good now.  :)